# White screen on Android Studio Emulator, Unable to access OpenGL ES Renderer

Tags: android-studio, opengl-es

Currently whenever I run my app on android studio, all that appears on the emualator is a white screen. I've looked at other answers to this same problem that say to make changes to OpenGL ES renderer to fix this issue, but when I go into my settings OpenGL is not an option there. Why would I not be able to access it, and what do I need to do to fix this?